# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver error keep coming

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, servlets, jdbc

I have added jar file to lib folder and linked with class path still getting the error as

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
>       at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1928)
>       at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1771)
>       at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
>       at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
>       at Registration.doGet(Registration.java:32)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110)
>       at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:498)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:1025)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:445)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1139)
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

i'm using eclipse as my IDE and Mysql as my DB with Mysql Workbench

Comment: Please add stacktrace of the error and the code you are trying to execute.

Comment: i have already added stack trace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To what kind of db You trying to connect, is it MySql ?

If so, you need to use `Class.forName("com.**mysql**.jdbc.Driver");`

Comment: it shows no suitable driver found....i have downloaded jconnetor jar and pasted in lib folder and added jar...pasted in tomcat lib folder and aslo in jre/lib/ext still getting the same error i.e NO SUITABLE DRIVER FOUND

Comment: try use maven dependency - > https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java/5.1.38